# Necessary and sufficient conditions for an adjoint of a linear map to be the map's inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space, $ \phi :V \rightarrow V$ a linear operator and $\phi^*:V \rightarrow V $ its adjoint.

I wish to show:

$\phi^*$ is an inverse to $\phi$ if and only if
$
\langle \phi (v), \phi (w) \rangle = \langle v,w\rangle
\ \ \forall \ v,w \in V
$

I understand that $\phi^* \circ\ \phi = id_V $ if and only if
$
\langle \phi (v), \phi (w) \rangle = \langle v,w\rangle
\ \ \forall \ v,w \in V.
$

The proof I'm reading then states, by rank-nullity, it is easily deduced that $\phi \circ\ \phi^* = id_v $.

How do I show the last part?

---

Here are the definitions I'm working with:

An inner-product is positive definite, linear in the second variable and conjugate symmetric.

An adjoint, $\phi^*$, is a linear operator with the property: $ \forall v,w  \in V, \langle \phi^*(v), w \rangle = \langle v, \phi(w) \rangle $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is [generally true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i) that for a finite dimensional space $V$ and linear operators $\psi,\psi':V \to V$, we have
$$
\psi\circ \psi' = \operatorname{id}_V \implies \psi' \circ \psi = \operatorname{id}_V
$$
This is sufficient to complete your proof.

Comment: Thanks :) Is there a name for this proposition?

Comment: No name that I'm aware of.  An algebraic way to put it is to say that "the ring $\Bbb F^{n \times n}$ is [Dedekind finite](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/dedekind-finite-rings/)".